# How does range work in this example?

Tags: clojure, anonymous-function, seq

Why is `(range)` in the following example able to reproduce index values? I would like to write a defn-defined function, but cannot see how this example works to reproduce what it does. I understand that # is creating an anonymous function.

So, assuming `(def d1 [:a :b :c])` how is range generating indexes in the following?

```
(#(map list % (range)) d1)
((:a 0) (:b 1) (:c 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range` returns an infinite sequence of integers, starting from zero. When `map` is passed two collection arguments, it calls `f` with two arguments, taking them pairwise from the collections. Thus, your `f` will be called once for each element `x` in `d1`, with two arguments: `x`, and its index in `d1`.

As an aside, please paste code that works, or at least makes sense. The `#` is in a nonsense place, and the parens don't balance.

Comment: The bulb illuminates. I've done so many `map #(` in line functions that I forgot about the multiple arguments to map. Also, thanks for noting the syntax. I fixed it, having copied it incorrectly out of the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

If we apply the anonymous function, we get `(map list d1 (range))`. `range` without arguments, creates a list from 2 to infinity. So we're calling `map` with `list` as the function argument and `d1` and a sequence from 0 to infinity as the other arguments. What `map` does is: it applies the given function to elements from the given sequences until one of the sequences runs out of elements. So the elements we get are `(list first-element-of-d1 first-element-of-range)`, `(list second-element-of-d1 second-element-of-range)` and so on until we've been over every element in `d1`.